# mount multiple windows shared folders in one Linux folder

Tags: mount, vsftpd

As title say, im trying to mount multiple windows shared folders in one of Linux folder. I have two hard disk/drives, and in each of them have Folders that are shared. This folders i like to put on my ftp server ( Linux CentOS ) so i can access them from outside. For example in my Windows PC i have D:\Move1...... and i have E:\Move2..... (D-one drive, E-other drive not partition.) I have CentOS and i have install vsftpd and i like to mount this two drives in the folder for example /ftp/moves/ and here all content from D:\Move1\ and E:\Move2\ to be in /ftp/moves (not as folders Move1 and Move2).

For now i have mount Move1 and its work ok, but when i try to add/mount the other one, the Move1 it disappear. I have just the last mount point that iv made ...

here is the /etc/fstab or how i mount them...

```
//10.5.5.10/Move1 /ftp/moves/     cifs    _netdev         0 0
//10.5.5.10/Move2 /ftp/moves/     cifs    _netdev         0 0
```